# Key Recovery Smart-Vercauteren SWHE

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

In the article (https://eprint.iacr.org/2009/571.pdf, pag 8) of Smart and Vercauteren, it is mentioned that the recovery of the private key is an instance of the small principal ideal problem. But I dont see how this is possible, since this implies that we know the ring in which we work, i.e. we know the polynomial $F$ chosen in the KeyGen() algorithm. But this is not public information. Am I getting this the wrong way ?

Comment: The polynomial $$F$$ defining the ring must be public, or an encrypter can't do the operations required to encrypt.

Comment: Can you be more specific? From what I understand the encryption only requires $p$ and $\alpha$: $$c=C(\alpha) \mod p$$ The only place where $F$ appears is in the KeyGen(), and I think the encryptor must not know its parameters

Comment: To run Mul requires knowing F, because one must reduce the product of ciphertexts modulo F. Also, one cannot encrypt without knowing the degree of F. It is definitely intended that the ring is public.

Comment: Actually you only need to know $p$ in order to run Mul and Add.Please check the pdf above. You are right about the degree of $F$, but $F$ could be kept secret and still get a correct scheme.

Comment: No, you really need to know F, they just aren't explicit about it in the notation. The reason is that you need to reduce mod F when you multiply, or the degree blows up and the scheme is not compact.

Comment: No you dont. Suppose we have $c_1,c_2 \in \mathbb{F}_p$ two cyphertexts. Mult($c_1$,$c_2$)=$c_1\cdot c_2$ mod $p$.We are able to multiply the two cyphertexts without using $F$

Comment: Oh yes you're right; I had forgotten that they represent everything in the HNF ($\mathbb{F}_p$) representation.  However, they still do intend for $F$ to be public, because a lot of information about it is leaked: we know a root mod $p$, and we must have bounds on the growth of polynomials under multiplication mod $F$.  See for example Lemma 2 and the paragraph immediately preceding it, where they say $F(x)=x^{2^n}+1$ in practice.  Moreover, it's at least plausible that from $pk=(p,\alpha)$ alone one could efficiently compute a suitable $F$, up to equivalences.